# tkinter - Run Function after Frame is Displayed

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

The code below has an onShowFrame function in the OtherPage class that runs when the OtherPage frame is shown. My problem is that everything in the  onShowFrame function runs before the frame is actually displayed to the user. I've demonstrated this with `time.sleep(5)`. What happens is the program sleeps for 5 seconds, remaining on BlankPage, before showing the OtherPage frame. I want the OtherPage frame to be shown first and then anything in the onShowFrame function to run.

How would I do this?

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

class Program(tk.Tk):        
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default = "")
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (BlankPage, OtherPage):

            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

        self.showFrame(BlankPage)

    def showFrame(self,cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
        frame.event_generate("<<ShowFrame>>")

###########################################################################################################
class OtherPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        self.controller = controller
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        innerFrame = tk.Frame(self)
        innerFrame.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="c", relwidth=1.0, relheight=1.0)

        innerFrame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        innerFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frameOne = tk.Frame(innerFrame)
        self.frameOne.grid()

        label = tk.Label(self.frameOne, text = "Other Page")
        label.pack()

        self.bind("<<ShowFrame>>", self.onShowFrame)

    def onShowFrame(self, event):
        time.sleep(5)

###########################################################################################################

class BlankPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        innerFrame = tk.Frame(self)
        innerFrame.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="c", relwidth=1.0, relheight=1.0)

        innerFrame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        innerFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frameOne = tk.Frame(innerFrame)
        self.frameOne.grid()

        button = tk.Button(self.frameOne, text = "Press", command = lambda: controller.showFrame(OtherPage))
        button.pack()

app = Program()
app.state('zoomed')
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to the fact that you're calling `sleep` *which causes the application to sleep*. In order for the display to update, the event loop has to be able to process events, which it cannot do while sleeping. To sleep literally means to stop *all* processing. The first six words of the documentation for `time.sleep` is **Suspend execution of the current thread**.

This is one place where calling `update` on a widget is a reasonable thing to do. It will give tkinter a chance to process all pending events -- such as the finishing of handling a button click, redrawing the window, etc -- *before* generating the new event.

It's as easy as changing your function to look like this:

```
def showFrame(self,cont):
    frame = self.frames[cont]
    frame.tkraise()
    frame.update()
    frame.event_generate("<<ShowFrame>>")
```

Comment: time.sleep was probably a bad example but the same thing happens with anything you put in the function. I only noticed this problem because the code I had there was taking a while to execute and caused lag between frame changes. Your solution works nonetheless.